# Problem with strong law of large numbers and sequence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, law-of-large-numbers

Show that ${X_n}$ is i.i.d and $E(X_1) = 1$ and $c_n$ is bounded real numbers

then $\frac{c_1 + ... + c_n}{n} \rightarrow 1$ if and only if $\frac{c_1X_1 + ... + c_nX_n}{n} \rightarrow 1$.

In the K.L. Chung A course in probability theory(3rd edition), there is hint s.t. truncate Xn at n and proceed as in Theorem 5.4.2(the Strong law of Large numbers).

But by separating integrals with the area of $j-1<|c_nX_n|<j$, since c_n can be 0 and cn is not same, applying the process of the proof of SLLN is not easy. Is there any another way to prove this?

--

Thank you for your answer. I solved it using another way.

As in the K.L.chung, define Yn = XnI(|xn| <= n), not Yn = anXn* I(|xn| <= n)
Then, the infinite sum of Var(anYn/n) converges similar to the proof of SLLN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a consequence of the (usual) law of large numbers, that is, $S_n/n\to\mathbb E\left[X_1\right]$, where $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$. Indeed, 
\begin{align}
\frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^nc_iX_i  &=\frac{c_n}nS_n+\frac 1n\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}j\left(c_j-c_{j+1}\right)\frac{S_j}j\\          
&=\frac{c_n}nS_n+\frac 1n\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}j\left(c_j-c_{j+1}\right)\left(\frac{S_j}j-1\right)+\frac 1n\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}j\left(c_j-c_{j+1}\right)\\
&=\frac{c_n}nS_n+\frac 1n\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}j\left(c_j-c_{j+1}\right)\left(\frac{S_j}j-1\right)+\frac 1n\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}j c_j -\frac 1n\sum_{j=2}^n\left(j-1\right)c_j   \\
&=\color{blue}{\frac{c_n}nS_n-\frac{n-1}nc_n   } +\frac 1n\sum_{j=1}^nc_j +\frac 1n\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}j\left(c_j-c_{j+1}\right)\left(\frac{S_j}j-1\right).     
\end{align}
Now, the conclusion follows if we manage to show that

- the blue term goes to zero and
- if $\varepsilon_n\to 0$, then $\frac 1n\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}j\left(c_j-c_{j+1}\right)\varepsilon_n\to 0$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! For the last term, I think that e_n should be replaced to e_ j. And I think this makes it hard. If it is a e_n for every j in the summation, the problem is quite easy because $\frac{c_1 + ... + c_n }{n}$ converges. But it is e_j, so, showing the last term converges to 0 is little bit hard( I tried $\frac 1n\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}j\left(c_j-c_{j+1}\right)\varepsilon_j$ <= $\frac 1n\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}|j|\left(|c_j-c_{j+1}|\right)|\varepsilon_j|$ ), but the existence of j makes it hard(changing the sum with $e_j-e_{j+1}$ doesn't help). Could you please explain a little bit more??